# How can I make a div only 'activate' when another button has already been clicked?

Tags: html, css, video, timer, popup

I'm trying to figure out how I can make a popup only show once a button has been clicked.  I've got a popup div on a timer, but I only want the timer to start after this button has been clicked.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

So I've got this button at the top that opens up this box that contains a HTML5 video that plays automatically; and I want the div with the popup in it to only start its timer of when to show up after that button has been clicked (so that the video is playing).

```
<button class="modal-open" >Begin Experience</button>
<div class="modal-box">
  <video class="fs-video" preload="auto" >
    <source  class="fs-video"  src="videos/scene1_option1a.mp4"  type="video/mp4" > 
    </video>    
</div>

<!--This is the popup code -->
    <div class="timer">
        <div class="modal">
        <p class="message">Look at this fancy pop-up</p>
            <div class="options">
                    <a href="test.html">
                <button class="btn">Yes</button>
                    </a>
                    <a href="test.html">
                <button class="btn">No</button>
                    </a>            
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>  
<!--end of popup code -->
```

This is the css I've used to make the timer:

```
.timer{
    animation: cssAnimation 0s 5s forwards;
    visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  to   { visibility: visible; }
}
```

Does that make sense to anybody?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some properties are not "transitionable" - visibility for example has only 2 states - visible or hidden, with no in between scale. As such an animation will not have the desired affect.

By using opacity instead, you can ensure a clean transition as the opacity property can be incremented.

With a little bit of JavaScript you can listen for a click on the button.

```js
let button = document.querySelector( "#button" );

button.addEventListener( "click", function( e ) {
  
  let timer = document.querySelector( ".timer" );
  timer.classList.toggle( "active" );
  
});
```

```css
.timer {
  opacity: 0;
}

.timer.active {
  animation: cssAnimation 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes cssAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="modal-open" id="button">Begin Experience</button>
<div class="modal-box">
  <video class="fs-video" preload="auto" >
    <source  class="fs-video"  src="videos/scene1_option1a.mp4"  type="video/mp4" > 
  </video>    
</div>

<!--This is the popup code -->
<div class="timer">
  <div class="modal">
    <p class="message">Look at this fancy pop-up</p>
    <div class="options">
      <a href="test.html">
        <button class="btn">Yes</button>
      </a>
      <a href="test.html">
        <button class="btn">No</button>
      </a>            
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>  
<!--end of popup code -->
```